# Ruby Return the content of a text(.txt) file after replacing variables

Tags: ruby, file, variables, text, extract

Imagine I have 2 files:

```
A.txt

This is a sentence with a #{variable}.
```

and a ruby script.

```
Iamascript.rb

...
variable = "period"
...
```

Is there any way I can read the content of the .txt file and insert the variable before puts'ing it?
This means my output when running the rb-script shall be

```
This is a sentence with a period.
```

The .txt file is dynamic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is commonly called *templating*, and you have basically defined a *template language*. Ruby actually ships with a template language called *ERb* in the standard library, so, if you are willing to change the syntax of your template language a bit, you can just use that instead of having to invent your own:

**A.txt**:

```
This is a sentence with a <%=variable%>.
```

**Iamascript.rb**

```
require 'erb'

variable = 'period'

puts ERB.new(File.read('A.txt')).result(binding)
# This is a sentence with a period.
```

Comment: Thank you, this works like  a charm for me. Is it also possible to read a hash from an external .txt or .rb file and use its keys (and values) in the "main"-code with this?

Comment: If you want to read pure data with no behavior, it is much better (both simpler *and* safer) to use a pure data description language for this, not a programming language. (And, after all, ERb allows you to embed *arbitrary* Ruby code, including, but not limited to, code that deletes all your data, formats your harddisk, starts a backdoor, etc.) If all you want is to read data, use a data language such as XML, YAML, or JSON. (I'd prefer JSON or YAML, not XML. Depends on the audience, i.e. the people who will have to edit that file.)

Comment: The project is not about pure data extraction, using templates would just be a case of convenience. I just like the idea to use a template for some pieces of code to have multiple (different) outputs without having to recode everything. But if you say it's a security concern I'll rather change my code everytime.

Answer (score 1):

There's one "obvious" (but bad) solution, that'd be eval. `eval` runs the bit of code you give it.

This is an issue for security concerns, but can be what you're looking for if you want if you need complex expressions in `#{...}`.

The more correct way to do it if you care even a tiny little bit about security is to use Ruby's formatting operator: `%` (similar to Python's).

```
template = "the variable's value is %{var}"
puts template % {var: "some value"} => prints "the variable's value is some value"
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the file `"A.txt"` contains the single line of text (or this line is extracted from the file):

```
s1 = 'This is a sentence with a #{my_var}'
```

and the second file, `"Iamascript.rb"`, contains:

```
s2 =<<_
line of code
  line of code
    my_var = "period"
  line of code
line of code
_
  #=> "line of code\n  line of code\n    my_var = 'period'\n  line of code\nline of code\n"
```

Let's create those files:

```
File.write("A.txt", s1)
  #=> 35
File.write("Iamascript.rb", s2)
  #=> 78
```

Now read the first line of `"A.txt"` and extract the string beginning `"\#{"` and ending `"}"`, then extract the variable name from that string.

```
r1 = /
     \#\{    # match characters
     [_a-z]+ # match > 0 understores or lower case letters
     \}      # match character
     /x      # free-spacing regex definition mode

s1 = File.read("A.txt")
  #=> "This is a sentence with a #{my_var}"
match = s1[r1]
  #=> "\#{my_var}" 
var_name = match[2..-2]
  #=> "my_var"
```

Now read "Iamascript.rb" and look for a line that matches the following regex.

```
r2 = /
     \A          # match beginning of string
     #{var_name} # value of var_name
     \s*=\s*     # match '=' and surrounding whitespace
     ([\"'])     # match a single or double quote in capture group 1
     ([^\"']+)   # match other than single or double quote in capture group 2
     ([\"'])     # match a single or double quote in capture group 3
     \z          # match end of string
     /x          # free-spacing regex definition mode
 #=> /
 #   \A          # match beginning of string
 #   my_var      # value of var_name
 #   \s*=\s*     # match '=' and surrounding whitespace
 #   ([\"'])     # match a single or double quote in capture group 1
 #   ([^\"']+)   # match other than single or double quote in capture group 2
 #   ([\"'])     # match a single or double quote in capture group 3
 #   \z          # match end of string
 #   /x
```

If a match is found return the line from `"A.txt"` with the text substitution, else return `nil`.

```
if File.foreach("Iamascript.rb").find { |line| line.strip =~ r2 && $1==$3 }
  str.sub(match, $2)      
else
  nil
end
  #=> "This is a sentence with a period"
```